# Computer hangs on Sleep. Need help reading dmp file

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sleep, windbg

My computer is hanging when it tries to enter sleep mode. The screen will turn off but the computer continues to run indefinitely. I have tried debugging it myself but it has exceeded my abilities. I used windows verifier to create a dmp file but I do not know what is important once opened in WinDbg. I appreciate any help in determining the problem and/or solution.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\080215-17253-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\SymCache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\SymCache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7601.18869.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150525-0603
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02e55000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`0309c730
Debug session time: Sun Aug  2 11:53:55.001 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:29.296
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.........
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck D3, {fffff8800102d2b9, 2, 0, fffff80002ef3c22}

Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!RtlDispatchException+122 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_PORTION_MUST_BE_NONPAGED (d3)
When possible, the guilty driver's name (Unicode string) is printed on
the bugcheck screen and saved in KiBugCheckDriver.
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers marking code or data as pageable when it should be
marked nonpaged.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff8800102d2b9, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff80002ef3c22, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80003106100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800031061c0
 fffff8800102d2b9 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!RtlDispatchException+122
fffff800`02ef3c22 410fb60c24      movzx   ecx,byte ptr [r12]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xD3

PROCESS_NAME:  WRSA.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff88002a0bbd0 -- (.trap 0xfffff88002a0bbd0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffff8800102a1dc rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff8800102d2d0
rdx=fffff8800102d0d2 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002ef3c22 rsp=fffff88002a0bd60 rbp=fffff88002a0cc18
 r8=000000000000017d  r9=000000000000016d r10=fffff88002a0d410
r11=fffff88002a0bda8 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
nt!RtlDispatchException+0x122:
fffff800`02ef3c22 410fb60c24      movzx   ecx,byte ptr [r12] ds:00000000`00000000=??
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002ec8e69 to fffff80002ec98c0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`02a0ba88 fffff800`02ec8e69 : 00000000`0000000a fffff880`0102d2b9 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`02a0ba90 fffff800`02ec7ae0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`000001e7 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`02a0bbd0 fffff800`02ef3c22 : fffff880`0102d2b9 fffff880`02a0bda8 fffff880`02a0cc18 fffff880`0100b000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`02a0bd60 fffff800`02f04e81 : fffff880`02a0cc18 fffff880`02a0c470 fffff880`00000000 fffff880`0104a090 : nt!RtlDispatchException+0x122
fffff880`02a0c440 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x135


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!RtlDispatchException+122
fffff800`02ef3c22 410fb60c24      movzx   ecx,byte ptr [r12]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!RtlDispatchException+122

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  556356e8

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18869

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD3_VRF_nt!RtlDispatchException+122

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD3_VRF_nt!RtlDispatchException+122

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xd3_vrf_nt!rtldispatchexception+122

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a7462664-d56e-ca97-7a53-f31727fb43aa}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

UPDATE:
I have uninstalled webroot. Running `verifier /standard /all` no longer causes a BSOD and dmp file but the issue with the sleep function remains. Any help on next steps is appreciated.

UPDATE 2:
The command `powercfg -a` produces the following

```
C:\windows\system32>powercfg -a
The following sleep states are available on this system: Standby ( S3 ) Hibernat
e Hybrid Sleep
The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

Update 3:
Couldn't seem to get sleep to initiate in safe mode. 
Output of `powercfg -energy`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5cnrhUem96xNjZWM3pMZ25oZDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have Webroot SecureAnyWhere installed **PROCESS_NAME:  WRSA.exe**. Uninstall it using [webroot uninstaller](http://download.webroot.com/WRUpgradeTool.exe) and see if it still crashes !

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean with Hanging and running indefinitely. Do you have to hard reboot after the computer hanging or does it just not enter sleep-mode *(but you can continue working whenever you want)*?

Comment: The screen will go black as if off but the fan continues to run and the LEDs do not indicate sleep mode. The power button that should wake it up does nothing. The only option is to hard reboot.

Comment: What does `powercfg -a` returns? *(run -> cmd -> powercfg -a)*

Comment: I have added the results to the post.

Comment: DId you try reproducing the error in safe mode?

Comment: It's pretty weird that S3 is supported but not S1 and S2. Please do in a command prompt as Administrator, enter `powercfg -energy > file`, wait 60 seconds and post the file online. For more info see [Use PowerCfg in Windows 7 to Evaluate Power Efficiency](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/). We will also need the exact model of your computer and the version of the BIOS (displayed when the computer boots). Is the computer fully patched including optional Windows Updates (except bing etc.)?

Comment: Please answer, if you want us to have a serious look into your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think you chose the wrong post for your bounty.

Comment: @harrymc - I was trying to improve the prospects for answers.  I will likely just let it die without awarding it.

Comment: @Ramhound: A pity. It might in the future be better to check first if the poster is still reacting.

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Is the computer fully patched including optional Windows Updates (except bing etc.)?

Comment: It definitely was in August when I first posted. I did run a batch of updates last night when I updated the post but I never got around to checking if there were more to do.

Comment: Reading the energy report I can see that there are 3 devices that wouldn't sleep - you should examine them. I would also counsel general checks like chkdsk and [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: I only have 24 hours left to award the bounty.  The current answers are less then desirable.  There isn't a single one that explains how to solve the problem described by the author.

Answer (score 1):

Give deleting the hibernation file a go.

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/

1. Run CMD as Administrator
2. `powercfg -h now`
3. Reboot
4. Ensure `hiberfil.sys` is deleted in `C:\`

You may need to ensure this setting is unchecked in View > Folder View of Windows Explorer to visually see the `hiberfil.sys` file.

[image]

5. Re-enable hibernation (in CMD running as Administrator): `powercfg –h on`
6. Reboot and retest

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced these sleep to resume issues typically with Network & WiFi cards on various laptops I have had over the decades.

More than likely, driver issues that could be bypassed in 2 ways:

- Find a driver - upgrade or downgrade - that works without sleep issues
- Switch / Turn off device e.g. Wireless connection before going to sleep and turn back on when resuming. This worked for me on many laptops from Compaq, HP, Dell, IBM & Lenovo Thinkpads.

Without going to deep into specifics of each device, device cards & buses being used and specific driver versions, this will not be easy/ direct to solve.

Specifics:

If you are using Vista drivers, as seen in the dump, then please upgrade drivers to Win 7/8 or downgrade to XP. The most horrible driver & WiFi experiences I had on my Thinkpad's were with Vista, and thankfully I could up to 7 or down to XP.

Answer (score -2):

I have experienced the same problem myself.
The steps I suggest you are:

1. Uninstall/Update all the drivers (Display/USB/network in particular)
2. Reset power management to default
3. Reinstall the operating system

Unfortunately, Step 3 was the resolution for me - however i have encountered a lot of users which step 1 solved the issue for them (It even can be a VPN or Virtualbox Network adapter in some cases)

I am sure however it is a software fault and not any hardware error/Failure.

Answer (score -2):

Most critical part of awaking a computer are driver procedures for returning the hardware in the same state as before sleeping.

May be you one of your drivers is responsible for the crash? Try updating your drivers. You could use some driver collection program - for example Driver Pack Solution - http://drp.su/